# How to add a text Autocomplete Widget programmatically

Tags: 6, entities, ajax

Trying to include a text Autocomplete Widget in a compound field (more [here](http://poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module)) using the snipped below.. but the field does not autocomplete. What am I doing wrong?

```
  $element['contact_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $defaults['contact_name'],
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#size' => '100',
    '#max_length' => '255',
    '#widget_type' => 'autocomplete_widgets_flddata',
    '#autocomplete_match' => 'contains',
    '#autocomplete_case' => '0',
    '#widget_module' => 'autocomplete_widgets',
  );
```

Comment: If you have firebug enabled, can you investigate the "Net" tab, to see what url is called to fetch the autocomple-data? And can you look if the response (by Drupal) is actual JSON autocomplete data?

Comment: please add a tag indicating your core version. I'm assuming it is 6 since you mention CCK.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so if you're trying to do it through hook_form_alter, you have to read the [documentation on altering CCK fields](http://drupal.org/node/726282).

The short version: the CCK fields are processed after the form is built. If you want to change anything in them, you have to add a callback to `$form['#after_build']` (but **do not replace the array**, just add to it). Then implement the function, change values in `$form` and return the `$form`.